# Is 'to make ~' the complement in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

Or, is it used as the meaning, 'Used to indicate something that is due or destined to happen,' as listed in the Oxford Dictionary?

I think the latter better fits in the context.

> Of cultivated crops, cereals were of the greatest economic importance
> in the Mediterranean region in ancient times, just as rice was the
> basic type of food in East Asia, and Indian corn and quinoa in the
> Americas. Since wild plants were necessarily self-seeding for their
> survival, the early Neolithic farmers favored individual plants that
> had developed suicidal mutations that prevented the pod from opening
> naturally and scattering the seed. Thus they were able to harvest
> their crops without losing grains, and could later separate the seeds
> from the pods. Similarly with animals: those that exhibited juvenile
> characteristics were favored over the strong, and bred to eliminate
> their wild characteristics. This ━ the earliest form of genetic
> manipulation by humans ━ was eventually ***to make*** a significant
> portion of Mediterranean flora and fauna dependent on human assistance
> in reproduction and survival: at least as sobering an innovation as
> the genetic modification of foods that is being debated at the
> beginning of the twenty first century.

[Ancient Technology](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=b76EBrop0sEC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=Thus%20they%20were%20able%20to%20harvest%20their%20crops%20without%20losing%20grains,%20and%20could%20later%20separate%20the%20seeds%20from%20the%20pods.%20Similarly%20with%20animals:%20those%20that%20exhibited%20juvenile%20characteristics%20were%20favored%20over%20the%20strong,%20and%20bred%20to%20eliminate%20their%20wild%20characteristics.&source=bl&ots=ysqJuZ6Pqi&sig=ACfU3U1iKmKU-Q421shgcIN62Ed3n2rycg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUgv-3xLPvAhUsbN4KHZdGB0oQ6AEwAXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=Thus%20they%20were%20able%20to%20harvest%20their%20crops%20without%20losing%20grains%2C%20and%20could%20later%20separate%20the%20seeds%20from%20the%20pods.%20Similarly%20with%20animals%3A%20those%20that%20exhibited%20juvenile%20characteristics%20were%20favored%20over%20the%20strong%2C%20and%20bred%20to%20eliminate%20their%20wild%20characteristics.&f=false)

Comment: Yes, it means that *at the time* of the beginning of genetic manipulation by humans, *in the future* (which is our past) the flora and fauna would become dependent on humans. The purpose of the statement is to explain that human dependence was a later side effect (not intended) of the earlier manipulation. This effect is in our past, but in the future for the humans who caused it.

Comment: It means the same as "would eventually make".

Comment: Thank you, epl and Jack O'Flaherty.